# Print quotient and remainder in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, division

I'm following this tutorial 
(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm)
 and write this piece of code. I like to print both, the quotient and the remainder, but I don't get the desired result.

This is the code:

```
   section .text
       global _start    

    _start:             
       mov  al,9
       mov  bl,2
       div  bl

       mov bl, al
       add bl, byte '0'
       mov [res], byte bl
       mov bl, ah
       add bl, byte '0'
       mov [tm], byte bl



       mov  ecx,msg
       mov  edx, len
       mov  ebx,1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
       mov  eax,4   ;system call number (sys_write)
       int  0x80    ;call kernel

       mov  ecx,res
       mov  edx,1
       mov  ebx,1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
       mov  eax,4   ;system call number (sys_write)
       int  0x80    ;call kernel

       mov  ecx,msg2
       mov  edx,len2
       mov  ebx,1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
       mov  eax,4   ;system call number (sys_write)
       int  0x80    ;call kernel

       mov  ecx,tm
       mov  edx,1
       mov  ebx,1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
       mov  eax,4   ;system call number (sys_write)
       int  0x80    ;call kernel



       mov  eax,1   ;system call number (sys_exit)
       int  0x80    ;call kernel

    section .data
    msg db "The result is:", 0xA,0xD 
    len equ $- msg
    msg2 db 0xA,0xD,"Remainder is:", 0xA,0xD
    len2 equ $- msg   

    segment .bss
    tm resb 1
    res resb 1
```

The result:

```
The result is:
4
Remainder is:
141%
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be `len2 equ $- msg2` (note the 2 after msg)?

Comment: Oh god! You're absolutelly right! Thanks

Answer (score -2):

%macro print 2
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,%1
mov edx,%2
int 80h
%endmacro

%macro read 2
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 2
   mov ecx, %1 
   mov edx, %2
   int 80h
%endmacro

section .data
   userMsg db 'Please enter a number: '
   lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg
   usermsg1 db 'enter 2nd number:'
   lenusermsg1 equ $-usermsg1
   quotient db ' quotient is : '
   quotientlength equ $-quotient
remainder db ' remainder is : '
   remainderlength equ $-remainder
   len EQU 16

section .bss           ;Uninitialized data
   n resb len
   n1 resb len

qtnt resb len
r resb len

section .text          ;Code Segment
   global _start
   _start:

print userMsg,lenUserMsg
read n,len 
print usermsg1,lenusermsg1
read n1,len

mov al,[n]
sub al,'0'

mov bl,[n1]
sub bl,'0'

div bl
add al,'0'
add dl,'0'
 mov [qtnt],al

print quotient,quotientlength
print qtnt,len

mov [r],dl

print remainder,remainderlength
print r,len

Exit:
 mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 80h

Comment: Please See this first: [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)